# What type of (young?) bird in the woods is this? (UK Lake District)

Tags: uk, bird-identification

I spotted this bird at the edge of [Stock Ghyll Woods](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/54.43161/-2.95325), near Ambleside in the UK's Lake District. The photo is from the start of June (just mentioning as the top feathers seem to be a bit more downy so thought it might be a younger bird, and that may affect the colouring?).

The call seemed more like a caw (than a song-bird for example) but if I remember correctly it kind of trilled the call rather than what a crow would do. Sorry for the vague details! I'm not up on birdwatching terms so hope the description is reasonably clear.

The bird was sitting in thick shrubs/trees but right out by the edge of the road (not deep in the woods) and was perched around waist height (just above & a little in from the  railing lining the footpath)

[image: Bird in the woods]

Comment: You can listen to the call [here](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/jay/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is indeed a young  Eurasian jay (Garrulus glandarius)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_jay

Comment: This is right. You may be interested in some more discussion on [jay plumage (juvenile vs. moulting)](https://community.rspb.org.uk/wildlife/f/ask-an-expert/106272/could-this-be-a-juvenile-jay)

Comment: @ChrisH — that's a good point re: juvenile vs moulting as it didn't look particularly small. Thanks for adding the call too! That's definitely it

Comment: @anotherdave because juveniles are fluffier than adults, in many species they don't look noticeably smaller.  Jays also fledge around 22 days and probably don't go far from the nest for a few more days so by the time you see the young they've had time to grow quite a bit